# How to auto answer incoming calls from a VOIP (voice over IP) on chrome /Firefox browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, voip

If a client is receiving calls on his browser (chrome/Firefox...etc) from a voice portal or VOIP , can i code an extension or a  plugin for the browser that automatically accepts the call once it comes to the browser and be the first one to catch it?

1-i tried coding auto clickers , but it wasn't as fast as required to make the client the first one to catch the call.

2-i thought of manipulating google chrome services that get called upon once the call comes to the browser but it was a dead end.

Comment: Are you using Twilio, JustCall or something else?

Comment: i don't know these things , i am a front end developer